# Dual sim unlocked Galaxy S9 - is it able to run Verizon AND T-Mobile simultaneously?

Tags: samsung, dual-sim, carriers

The Galaxy S9+ supports dual sim cards.  If buying an unlocked one, can it have both Verizon and T-Mobile running on it at once?

Also, if so, how does it know which one to use for data like if using tethering?

Comment: I don't know about the S9, but most dual-SIM phones that I've seen only use the secondary SIM for calls and SMS, and not data. It's essentially just a means of providing a second phone number for the device. Only the primary SIM is used for data.

Comment: @eldarerathis Okay, thanks.  Do you know if it would be able to use both T-Mobile and Verizon for calls and SMS?